# How to set up NSFetchedResultsController, passing in Entity name in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In Swift, when you declare a NSFetchedResultsController like below, you have to state the type of result that the `NSFetchedResultsController` will be returning, e.g. `NSFetchedResultsController<Quote>`:

```
fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Quote> = {
    // Create Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Quote> = Quote.fetchRequest()

    // Configure Fetch Request
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

    // Create Fetched Results Controller
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    // Configure Fetched Results Controller
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

If I wanted to use the same tableview with two different Core Data Entities and I injected a value for the entity into the `UITableViewController` as either a `String` or an `Enum` how would I go about rewriting the code to reflect the injected value?

Comment: Could you rephrase and clarify your question please? I'm not sure what you mean by 'injecting a value for the entity into the `UITableViewController`'. What 'value' is your code example currently 'injecting' for example?

Comment: Hi silicon_valley - dependency injection is where a value is passed into another object for it to use rather than the object creating a value itself. So i have a view where the user makes a choice of which entity and that is passed onto the next view (the tableview which I want to power with a NSFetchedResultsController) . Back in the objective c days i could pass a string value for the entity name and build a single  fetch results controller using the string - now it appears that I have to declare an NSFetchedResultsController as being a  NSFetchedResultsController for a specific  type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to inject. You get automatic type inference throughout.

When you say `Quote.fetchRequest()`, you automatically get a `NSFetchRequest<Quote>` as its result. You then use that fetch request in the initializer of an NSFetchedResultsController and you automatically get a `NSFetchedResultsController<Quote>`. One entity type, one fetch request type, one result controller type.

If you have *another* entity type you just use *another* fetched results controller.

Comment: So, Matt, are your just suggesting having the code for two separate NSFetchedResultsControllers and just choosing which one to fire up based on which entity name i pass in ?

Comment: I'm certainly "suggesting having the code for two separate NSFetchedResultsControllers". As to how you choose which one to use, I have nothing say about that, as I don't know your purpose here. — Basically, you are suffering from the fact that Swift imports NSFetchedResultsController and NSFetchRequest as generics; there is no string entity name in the story any more. Apple thought it was doing us all a favor with this, but obviously it makes what you would have done in Objective-C impossible. You could, I suppose, just write this part of your code in Obj-C if it's important to you.

Comment: cheers matt. Just as well there aren't 17 possible Entities i want to pass in :)